# How can I merge a branch in a local repository to a branch that is in another local repository

Tags: git, merge, branch

Suppose I have 2 local repositories.

```
Local Repository A //Cloned from production remote repository.

Local Repository B //Cloned from development remote repository.
```

From the Local Repository A, I created my own feature branch called

```
FeatureA //In Local Repository A
```

After finishing the FeatureA from the Local Repository A, I want to merge this FeatureA branch into a branch called

```
Developer //In Local Repository B
```

Notice, how two branches, FeatureA and Developer, are in a different local repositories.

How can I merge the FeatureA branch into Developer branch ?

Comment: Why are you using two different repositories for `production` and `development`, as opposed to a proper CI/CD process? That way you would only need to worry about one repository, and could deploy branches to target environments (or upon certain conditions).

Comment: @Obsidian Age To be honest, I am not sure why my company is working like this. And I am a new developer. I will have to ask the team lead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this answer for my future reference.

I wrongfully thought that there existed two different remote repositories (one for production and one for development).

It turns out, there is only one remote repository for this project.

Here is what I should have done instead.

1. From the remote repository, clone it into my local machine only once.
2. Then checkout the Production branch on my local machine.
3. Make my own branch off of the Production branch I just checked out.
4. After finishing the feature, merge my branch into Developer branch.

Answer (score 1):

Git does not actually merge *branches*.  In fact, like most things in Git, *branches* don't matter at all here: only the *commits* matter.  Git merges *commits*.

What this means for you is that you can only get a proper result if all the *commits* are related.  (They probably are, but we can't see that.  *You* can find that out.)

## Long

There are a few important things to know about commits (this is not a complete list, but important here for merging):

- They're found via hash IDs.
- The hash IDs are large, ugly, and random-looking (not actually random, but quite unpredictable, and unusable by humans).
- Commits refer to other, earlier commits by hash ID.  That's fine for the *commits themselves*, which are after all read by a computer program (or series of computer programs: we call these programs `git`), but not much good for the hapless humans supposedly in charge of these programs and computers.

Because of these particular bullet points, Git makes a big concession to humans: it will let us use *branch names* to find commits.  Not only that, it has a special feature just for humans.  When we:

1. first direct Git to be "on" some particular branch, then
2. direct Git to make a *new* commit,

Git will *update the branch name that we're "on"* so that this name now refers to the *new* commit, instead of referring to whichever specific commit it meant just a moment ago.

For ordinary, single-parent commits, we can draw this situation like this.  We start by replacing the real hash IDs that the real commits have with fake, single-letter pseudo-IDs that *we* pick to work with our feeble human brains.  Then we draw each commit with an arrow coming out of it, pointing backwards to one *earlier* commit.  This puts the *latest* commit on the right:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

So here `H` stands in for the hash ID of the *latest* commit.  Somewhere inside the internal representation *of* commit `H`, Git has saved away the true hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  We draw this as an arrow coming out of our representation of `H`, pointing to our representation of `G`.

Of course, `G` itself is also a commit, so it also has a stored previous-commit hash ID: `G` points to `F`.  `F` likewise points to some earlier commit, and so on.  This repeats forever, or rather, until we get back to the very first commit ever: commit `A` in this formulation.  (Our repository thus has a paltry eight commits.)

For StackOverflow purposes, due to laziness and/or font issues, I tend to stop drawing the commit-to-commit arrows *as* arrows and do this instead:

```
A--B--...--G--H
```

but in fact each connection from commit to commit goes only one way: from the *later* commit, e.g., `H`, to the earlier one.  This is because commits, once made, are completely, totally, 100% read-only.  Not a single bit *in* a commit can ever change.<sup>1</sup>

When we add branch names to these drawings, their workings become much clearer.  Let's say we have two names, `main` and `develop`, and *both names point to commit `H`, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, develop
```

This means all commits up through and including `H` are on *both branches*.  We must now pick *one* branch to be "on", using `git checkout` or `git switch`:<sup>3</sup>

```
git switch main
```

To remember which branch we're using, we add the special name `HEAD`, written in all uppercase like this, attached to just one of these branch names:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), develop
```

This indicates that we are *using* commit `H` *via* the *name `main`*.

The checkout or switch command works by (very roughly):

- removing from the work area—which Git calls the *working tree*—all the files that came out of some *other* commit, if / as needed;
- filling in this work area with all the files from the commit we've just switched *to*.

We'll see this in action in a moment, but for now, let's switch to `develop`, or even create a new branch name `feature`.

---

<sup>1</sup>This read-only property is required to make the hashing scheme work.  The hash ID *of* a commit is simply a cryptographic checksum of all the bits stored in that commit.  If you take a commit out of a Git database, turning it into ordinary data, then modify that data in some way and put it back into the Git database, what you get is a *new and different commit* with a *new and different hash ID*.  The old commit remains, unchanged, under the old ID.

Git verifies, at object-extraction time, that all the bits that come *out* of the database still checksum to the original value.  If they don't, Git declares the database corrupt, and ceases to function.  Since file contents are also stored using this same hashing trick, that's how we can be sure that none of our files are ever damaged.  Once they're *in* the repository, they're in there forever<sup>2</sup> and can never be changed.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, it's possible to strip commits out of a repository database, but it's tricky and we won't cover it here.

<sup>3</sup>There's no difference here between these uses of `checkout` and `switch`.  Certain historical mistakes with `git checkout` were eventually cleaned up by splitting that one command, `checkout`, into two separate commands, `switch` and `restore`, and it makes sense to learn the new ones as long as you are not forced to use an old version of Git that lacks the new ones.  (I have been using Git for more than 15 years at this point though so I have old and sometimes not-so-good habits here.  If I use `git checkout`, it's by habit, or because someone gave me a Git 1.7 version to update, perhaps.)

---

#### Making new commits on a branch

If we now switch to existing branch `develop`, we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, develop (HEAD)
```

To do this, Git would need to remove all the files that came out of commit `H`, and instead, put in all the files from commit `H`.  This kind of remove-and-replace-with-sameness is obviously stupid, so Git *skips this step for this particular case*.<sup>4</sup>  Git doesn't remove or replace any files at all *this* time.  So if we start making changes but forget to switch to a different branch (or create a new branch; see below) it's generally safe to do that as soon as you notice your error.

Anyway, now that we're on `develop`, let's make a new commit in the usual way.  I will skip over a lot of important detail—in particular, I won't mention Git's *index* aka *staging area*—and will just assume that you know everything there is to know here;<sup>5</sup> and however, we do it, we now have Git make a new commit, which we will call `I`.:

```
          I
         /
...--G--H
```

New commit `I` points backwards to existing commit `H`.  But now the special magic trick happens: **Git writes the new commit's hash ID into the current branch name**, i.e., the one that has `HEAD` attached.  So to complete our drawing—and see why I put `I` on a line by itself here—we draw this:

```
          I   <-- develop (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

Note how the name `develop` now points to the *new* commit.  All the other branch names are untouched: only the name `develop` moved.

If we make a second new commit `J`, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

Commits up through `H` are on *both branches*, while new commits `I-J` are only on `develop`.

If we now run `git checkout main` or `git switch main`, we get this:

```
          I--J   <-- develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

This time, Git really does have to remove some files—those specific to commit `J`—and replace them with the right files for commit `H`.  So Git does that, and if we now examine our files, we'll see that we have the files from commit `H`.<sup>6</sup>

Now that we're back on commit `H` via the name `main`, let's make a *new branch name*.  We have to pick some commit for this new name to point-to, and the usual choice is "the commit we're on now", i.e., commit `H`:

```
git switch -c feature    # or git checkout -b feature
```

This leaves us in this state:

```
          I--J   <-- develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD), main
```

If we now make two *more* commits, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- develop
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

We now have a state in which merging makes sense.

---

<sup>4</sup>This skipping is achieved in a smarter way than described here, but for the "switch branches without switching commits", the effect is that the change is always allowed.  In more complicated cases, you get odd effects; see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452) for the gory details.

<sup>5</sup>There is a lot to know!  For more details, see other answers or Git tutorials.

<sup>6</sup>This is where the complications mentioned in footnote 4 can come in.  Files that we *forgot to commit*, or *deliberately didn't commit*, can be carried along in the working tree and/or in Git's index aka staging-area.  But if we made sure to commit everything in `I` and `J`, we'll be in a "clean" state, as reported by `git status`, before and after the checkout—unless things get *really* complicated, but let's not go there.

---

#### Merging is about combining work

Let's draw this again but change some names, switch branches around, and drop the name `main` entirely (it's in the way):

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

We're now using commit `J` via name `br1`.  We can run:

```
git merge <hash-of-L>
```

or:

```
git merge br2
```

to have Git locate commit `L` and do the work of a merge.  Or, if we aren't ready to merge commit `L` yet, but want to merge in commit `K`, we can run:

```
git merge <hash-of-K>
```

That is, we'd run `git log br2` and see commit `L`, then see commit `K`.  It has some big ugly hash ID, `b789abc...` or whatever, and we'd grab that with the mouse, cut-and-paste style, and produce a command like:

```
git merge b789abc
```

(abbreviated hash IDs work too, so you can retype the first 4 or 7 or 15 characters and stop, but it's way too easy to make a mistake here: I always use cut-and-paste for this).

We generally don't bother to merge with some number of commits back like this, but in some complicated cases—e.g., if we have:

```
          o--o--...--o   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--...--(thousands of commits)--...--o   <-- br2
```

we might want to break the merge up into smaller chunks, picking some commit somewhere along the very long line of `br2` to merge in first:

```
          o--...--o---M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /           /
...--o--*           /
         \         /
          o--...--o--(hundreds of commits)--...--o   <-- br2
```

Having merged in just 500 commits, we took an original 1400 commits down to 900 left to merge; we can do another 500, leaving only 400 left to merge, etc.

In any case, regardless of how *many* commits we are merging, the merge operation works the same way.  Given:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

and `git merge br2`, Git:

- finds the current commit `J` (that's easy: Git uses `HEAD`);
- finds the other commit `L` (that's easy: Git uses `br2`, which we gave it); and
- finds the *merge base* commit, commit `H`: that's harder.

Git *finds* that merge base commit through [an algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs), but we can just describe at as the *best common ancestor*, and in this case it's simply commit `H`.<sup>7</sup>

Git now uses the snapshots in each commit—we haven't described this properly, but each commit holds a full snapshot of every file—to figure out "what we changed" on "our branch" `br2`, by diffing commit `H` vs commit `J`, and to figure out "what they changed" on "their branch" by diffing commit `H` vs commit `L`.  The three commits to diff here are:

- the merge base, on the left of *both* `git diff` commands;
- our current or `HEAD` commit, on the right of the "ours" diff;
- the commit we chose to merge, on the right of the "theirs" diff.

The output from the two diffs determines the set of changes to merge.

The merge algorithm now *combines* these changes, applies the *combined* changes to the snapshot in the merge base commit—commit `H` here—and thus *keeps our changes* while *adding their changes*, which is what we want.

Having successfully combined these two sets of changes and applied them to the merge base, Git now makes a new commit from the result.<sup>8</sup>  That new commit is a *merge commit*, which is special in exactly one way: instead of pointing back to a single parent, it points back to *two* parents, like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

The *first* parent of new merge commit `M` is the commit we were using when we ran `git merge`, i.e., commit `J`.  The *other* parent is the commit we named on the command line, commit `L` in this case.  Merge commit `M` has, as its snapshot of all files, the result of the combining-and-applying-to-`H`'s-snapshot.

---

<sup>7</sup>As the Wikipedia article notes, there is not necessarily a single unique LCA node in a DAG.  For these cases, the merge algorithm gets trickier; we won't cover those here.

<sup>8</sup>If Git *fails* to combine the changes, it deliberately stops in the middle of the merge, leaving us a mess to clean up.  We won't cover that case here either.

---

#### What this means for you

For `git merge` to do its job, the commits you give it must:

- all be in one repository; and
- be *related*, in terms of having some best shared commit: `H` in our example above.

When you have a single repository, the first condition is trivially satisfied—all the commits are in *the* (single) repository—and the second is usually the case because we normally make a *new* branch by growing it from some starting point that's on some existing branch.  That shared *starting point* commit is *a* common starting point and therefore *a* shared commit.  If there have been merges since then, there may be some *better* shared commit, but otherwise this is *the* shared commit:

```
 ...--*--*--*--o--o   <-- br1 (HEAD)
             \
              o----o   <-- br2
```

The starred commits `*` are on both branches, so the rightmost one works as the merge base.  Or:

```
 ...--*--*--*--o--o--M1--o--o   <-- br1 (HEAD)
             \      /
              *----*----o----o   <-- br2
```

Again, all the starred commits are on both branches.  The extra parent of merge commit `M1` joins `br2` back into `br1`, so once again, the rightmost starred commit works as the merge base.  Once we make merge `M2` we have:

```
 ...--*--*--*--o--o--M1--o--o--M2   <-- br1 (HEAD)
             \      /         /
              *----*----*----*   <-- br2
```

Note how merging "adds" all the other branch's commits to `br1`.

When you have *two separate repositories*, though, are the commits related?  Now we get into one of the complications with any distributed version control system, like Git.

When you *clone* a Git repository, you literally *copy* the commits.  A `git clone` of some repository **R** makes some clone **C**, but **C** has all the commits from **R**.<sup>9</sup>  In Git, cloning copies the commits, but *doesn't copy the branches*,<sup>10</sup> which in some sense is weird—Mercurial copies the branches too, for instance—but the important thing for your case is that the *commits* get copied.

Now, *after* the commits are copied into **C**, someone can make more commits in **R**, and/or someone else can make more commits in **C**.  But if they both follow the same sort of standard procedure—of starting with the commits they have, and merely *adding on*—these commits will all "join up in the past", in exactly the same way we get with a *single* repository.

All you have to do, in this case, is:

- clone either of **R** or **C** into a *third* Git repository, then
- *add to that repository* all the commits that are in the *other* of these two repositories, that aren't already in your third clone.

That second step—"add commits that we don't have"—might seem like a big thing.  In some ways, it is ... but *we already have to do that because of cloning*.  That is, suppose there's some "source of truth" repository **R<sub>central</sub>** that *everyone* clones.  You make your clone **C<sub>you</sub>**.  Alice makes clone **C<sub>alice</sub>**, Bob makes clone **C<sub>bob</sub>**, and so on.

At some point, *somebody* makes new commits, and eventually—somehow—gets their commits into **R<sub>central</sub>**.  And now *everybody with a clone* has to get *those* new commits into their clones, if they want to see them and use them.  So we have `git fetch`.

We run `git fetch name`.  Git calls the *`name`* we use here a *remote*.  When you clone **R<sub>central</sub>**, your Git, in your clone **C**, adds a standard remote name, `origin`.  Your Git stores the URL of **R<sub>central</sub>** under this standard name, and from now on, you can just run:

```
git fetch origin
```

to have your Git call up the **R<sub>central</sub>** Git.  They will list out their commits (by hash ID) and their branch names (by name), and your Git will figure out if any of those commits are *new to you*, and if so, obtain them.  Your Git will then set up *remote-tracking names* by taking their *branch* names, `main` and `feature` and whatever, and sticking `origin/` in front of them: the `origin` part comes from the *remote*.  These names "track"<sup>11</sup> the branch names over on `origin`, so they are the *remote-tracking* names for `origin`.

**You can add more Git repositories as additional remotes.**  That is, using:

```
git remote add repo-xyz <url>
```

you add a second remote, using the name `repo-xyz`, to store the given *`url`*.  Now you can run:

```
git fetch repo-xyz
```

Your Git will call up the Git at the URL you just saved, ask them about *their* branch names and commit hash IDs, and bring over any commits they have, that you don't.  Your Git will then create, in your clone **C**, remote-tracking names of the form `repo-xyz/*`.  You'll have a `repo-xyz/main` if they have a `main`.  If they have a `develop`, you'll have a `repo-xyz/develop`.

Each of these remote-tracking names will remember exactly one commit hash ID, just as each *branch* name in **C**, **R<sub>central</sub>**, or this added remote remembers exactly one commit hash ID.  Because `git fetch` reads their *current* state, your remote-tracking names will now remember their *branch* state as of the time you ran `git fetch`.

So, having run `git fetch origin` *and* `git fetch repo-xyz`, you now have:

- all the commits you had, plus
- all the commits `origin` had that you didn't, plus
- all the commits `repo-xyz` had that you didn't, plus
- remote-tracking names `origin/*` and `repo-xyz/*` to remember branch names and commit hash IDs from `origin` and `repo-xyz`.

Remote-tracking names, which locate specific commits, work just as well as branch names for locating specific commits.  So you can pass a remote-tracking name to `git merge`.  The only thing they *don't* work for here is that you cannot get "on" a remote-tracking name.  That's because it is not a *branch* name, and Git will only let you attach `HEAD` to a *branch* name.  If you want a branch name to point to some commit that some existing remote-tracking name locates, you can use `git checkout` or `git switch` to do this:

```
git switch -c update-some-abc-branch repo-xyz/abc-branch
```

Because you have *two* remotes (`origin` and `repo-xyz`), you may run into the annoyance that you can't make one name, like `main`, that you work with when working with *both* `origin/main` *and* `repo-xyz/main`.  You may need to use some funky mismatched branch names, like I just did above.  That works fine: there's no need to use the *same* names in each repository.<sup>12</sup>

This gives you all the information you need to:

- create branch names in *your* repository **C** to locate specific commits while getting "on" those branches;
- run `git merge` with the *commits* identified by your branch names and/or your remote-tracking names.

As long as you remember that what Git really cares about are the *commits and their hash IDs*, and that *your* branch names are just there to let you find *your chosen commits*, you'll be fine.

---

<sup>9</sup>It's possible to make clones that omit some commits, but we'll consider the usual case where we *don't* do that.

<sup>10</sup>Git uses, instead, *remote-tracking names*.  Copying *branch* names would be possible but would lead to confusion.  The remote-tracking name technique leads, instead, to ... confusion.  I'm not sure there's that much of an improvement here.  But it is what it is.

<sup>11</sup>Git badly overuses this verb *track*.  Again, though, it is what it is.  Git calls these things *remote-tracking branch names*, but they are not actually *branch* names, so I use *remote-tracking names* as they are names and they do track other (remotes') names.

<sup>12</sup>This is where the Mercurial method, of forcing everyone to use the same branch names, is so helpful.  It's also where the Mercurial method, of forcing everyone to use the same branch names, is so hurtful.  It all depends on what you need to get done.